# Chrome newtab white flash on light theme with black background

Tags: google-chrome, themes, dark-mode

I am trying to use chrome in light mode, while keeping the newtab pages black. I don't want to use dark mode because it looks way better when I have light colors on tabs. I also want to keep my bookmarks only visible on newtab, so it's not okay for me to use a customized newtab, or a webpage like google.com.

Dark mode extensions won't work on newtab, and themes are not customizable to work only on specified pages. The themes that work only on newtab won't let me use the vanilla google search page and I will get a completely different page.

The closest thing I found is to place a simple color as background but it displays a white page before loading.

I used to have a theme that did exactly what I wanted, but I accidentally removed it and now I can't find it anywhere. I cannot find my previously used themes list either.

I have noticed some old questions having similar problems, but they are both old and different cases.

So, any idea is appreciated.